# What is the fastest way to generate custom column values in Postgres while importing data with \COPY?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm loading ~45 million records from a CSV file with `\COPY`. The data contains x, y, z values representing 3D coordinates.

```sql
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  id         integer,
  x          double precision,
  y          double precision,
  z          double precision,
  coordinate geometry default NULL,
  CONSTRAINT mytable_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

The `geometry` type is coming from [postgis](https://postgis.net/). I'd like to create the `coordinate` value on the fly with [`ST_MakePoint(x, y, z)`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html) while importing the data. Currently, I'm using a trigger for this purpose, but it significantly slows down the import.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_coordinates()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
  update mytable set coordinate = ST_MakePoint(NEW.x, NEW.y, NEW.z) where id = NEW.id;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER create_coordinates_trigger
  AFTER INSERT
  ON mytable
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE create_coordinates();
```

Is there a better aproach for creating custom column values while importing data?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, @jjanes! Luckily it was only a copy/paste error (I simplified the sql a bit before posting). It's fixed now.

Comment: Unrelated, but: the language name is an identifier and should not be enclosed in single quotes. The syntax is deprecated and this may fail in a future version

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name! I'll make sure to remove them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting in v12, you can use a generated column.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable2 (
  id         integer,
  x          double precision,
  y          double precision,
  z          double precision,
  coordinate geometry generated always as (ST_MakePoint(x, y, z)) stored,
  CONSTRAINT mytable2_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

In my hands, this seems to be about 6 times faster to bulk load than the trigger version, (even more for very larger imports)

And if you don't want to us this newish feature, just turning the AFTER trigger into a BEFORE trigger is also several times faster.  Rather than doing an update after the fact, you just alter the row before ever inserting it:

```
NEW.coordinate = ST_MakePoint(NEW.x, NEW.y, NEW.z);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping for. It takes about 4 minutes to import the data this way on my machine, compared to ~16 minutes with my original solution. Thank you!